# Information Gain and attributes

Tags: classification, feature-selection, overfitting, supervised-learning, feature-engineering

In the [book](https://www.amazon.it/dp/0321321367/ref=asc_df_032132136752413000/?tag=googshopit-21&creative=23390&creativeASIN=0321321367&linkCode=df0&hvdev=c&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=&th=1&psc=1) i'm reading about Data Mining, in the chapter about decision tree it's said that the **information gain test** is biased towards tests with many outcomes (attributes having a large number of values).

However, the author doesn't give a proof of this statement, neither an **intuitive** one. Can you help me to understand why ?